# Eigenvalue problem - Right hand matrix is singular

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, programming

I am constructing an eigenvalue problem of the form

$$[R]{c} = \lambda [F]{c}$$

The matrices are populated by the results of some integrals

$$ 
I_{i,j} = \int f(x,y,i,j) dxdy \quad for \quad i=1,..,N \quad j=1,...,M
$$

All the numbers are coming out wrong the eigenvalues are nonsensical and do not converge as the matrices get larger, they just get larger in turn, and I am trying to troubleshoot. I noticed that $[F]$ always is singular. I added some "salt" ($1e-10$) so that the program did not rebel on me but I am thinkning that this might indicate some deeper issue about my problem formulation/computation, although I am not really sure what.

So my question is: Does the fact that $[F]$ is singular, point to any such problems and if yes how should I go about correcting it? Furthermore any advice on where to focus the troubleshooting?

Cheers

Comment: Your issue is about the so-called "generalized eigenvalue problem". See paragraph 7.3 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix.

Comment: I would try at first to convert your issue into the eigenvalue problem $F^+Rc=\lambda c$ where $F^+$ is the pseudo-inverse of $F$.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it

Comment: If you use Matlab or a similar software (Octave), you can get directly the answer. I cite : " [V,D] = eig(A,B) produces a diagonal matrix D of generalized eigenvalues and a full matrix V whose columns are the corresponding eigenvectors so that A*V = B*V*D."

Comment: I do the calculations using scipy.linalg.eig(R,b=F), so I know that the problem is not with the calculation of the eigenvalues itself but with my formulation. I use scipy for the det() and inv() calculations as well

Comment: Maybe, If you explain a little more your issue, its context, what is the problem at hand, the size of the matrices, etc, some among us can have a certain idea. For example, what is the spectrum of the singular values of $F$ (more interesting here than the eigenvalues)... Is one of your matrices $E$ or $F$ with a particular structure (symmetric, psd...), etc.

Comment: I am trying to find the lowest value that would cause buckling on a composite plate. This would be the lowest eigenvalue, and the program should converge on that solution as the matrices get larger. Here is a sample $R$ matrix:

Here an F matrix:

Comment: $$R =

\begin{array}{cccc}
  0.8334971    & 4.17815877  & 13.86869435  & 34.56910269\\
  4.63449654  & 13.83872632  & 33.52342807  & 69.92804483\\
  16.28196565  & 35.93753681  & 69.83052589 & 126.14788633\\
  41.73478583  & 78.23144509 & 132.15137615 & 216.12985001\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Typical (singular) F matrix

$$ F =
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2.4674011  & 2.4674011 & 2.4674011 & 2.4674011\\
 9.8696044  & 9.8696044 & 9.8696044 & 9.8696044\\
22.2066099 & 22.2066099 & 22.2066099 & 22.2066099\\
39.4784176 & 39.4784176 & 39.4784176  & 39.4784176\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Sorry for late answer. A first fundamental observation is that this $F$ matrix is not only singular, but "very very singular" because all its lines are equal (a rank one matrix). Is this is always the case ?

Comment: It is in this configuration unfortunately (and it has to work in this configuration as well), because the $ F$ matrix is generated from this integral

$$
I_{7} = \frac{i}{j} (\frac{\pi i}{2} + \frac{sin(\pi i)(cos(\pi i))}{2})(\frac{\pi j}{2} - \frac{sin(\pi j)(cos(\pi j))}{2})
$$

Since $sin(k \pi) = 0$ we are left with only

$$
I_{7} = \frac{i}{j} (\frac{\pi i}{2})(\frac{\pi j}{2}) = \frac{i^2 \pi^2}{4}
$$

So it only depends on $i$ and all the columns are the same

Comment: I understand. Thus, is my solution useful to you ?

Comment: I'll put it in code and see how it does. My linear algebra leaves much to be desired so I can't really see from just reading it whether it will work or not. By the way thanks again for your continued assistance, I appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how I can mark a comment as the correct answer but after much pain and tears, using the pseudo-inverse matrix as suggested by Jean Marie yielded the best results. Not completely there yet, the resulting eigenvalues are always what I am looking for divided by 2 for some reason, but it's getting there.

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ is rank one (as in the example you gave) the generalized eigenproblem

$$Rc=\lambda Fc \tag{1}$$

has indeed (according to you terms) a "deeper" issue.

Indeed, if $F$ is rank one, we can write it under the form :

$$F=C \mathbb{U}^T \ \tag{2}$$

with $C$ any column of $F$, (e.g. $2.4, 9.8,22.2,39.4$ in the example you have given) and $ \mathbb{U}$ the column vector of $\mathbb{R^4}$ with null entries.

Thus (1) becomes $Rc=\lambda C(\mathbb{U}^T c)$ ; as  parentheses enclose in fact a number, one gets $Rc=\mu C$ for a certain $\mu$ ; otherwise said (provided $R$ is invertible):

$$c=\mu R^{-1}C \ \tag{3}$$

giving a a unique family of (generalized) eigenvectors ($\mu$ has no constraint on it).

Having an eigenvector, it is of course easy to get the corresponding eigenvalue.

Remark : in fact, of course, this reasoning works as well in nD.

Comment: $ \mu = \lambda (U^{T}c)$ ?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Has my answer been satisfying for you ?

Comment: The final answer has not been much of a help to be honest, but the suggestion of the pseudoinverse has helped a lot, mainly since I was not aware of its existence sadly. After a lot more tweaking on different parts of the code it yielded the best results. Thank you very much for taking all this time to help

Comment: I understand. Nevertheless, there was another side in my contribution : the remark that your matrix has identical columns (= rank one).

Comment: ... this kind of extreme redundancy make me think that maybe a matrix approach is not the most adequate for this issue.

Comment: The aforementioned other changes fixed that, [F] no longer has identical columns, although I am not exactly sure why, I have been struggling with the bizarre behaviour of SymPy (the package I am using for symbolic calculations) for some time now but I can't really say I understand it yet

Comment: But I would like to know what you have in mind, so please elaborate

Comment: If your matrix is no longer with the same columns, forget this remark...